# Step out of vs step out from

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

What is the correct way of commanding students in school assembly conduction, "**step out from** your line and come front" or "**step of** your line and come front" which one is the correct one?

"Step out from" or "step of" ?

Comment: You don't need *from*. Using *out* implies the motion involved. "Step *out of (the) line* and come forward." Use *forward* as this indicates motion.

Answer (score 3):

I think "step out from" is better, and you need to say "come to the front," not "come front," which is not grammatical (at least in American English).

"Step out of your line" could also work fine and is perfectly comprehensible; I just don't like the way it recalls the idiomatic expression "step out of line," which means "to break the rules" or "act inappropriately":

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/step+out+of+line